# How to detect if request is made using collection route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Ruby on rails has a feature to easily create collection routes for resources. But in the controller, how do we detect if that collection route is matched for the current request.

```
resource :posts, :only => [:index, :show] do
  collection do
    get :archived, :action => :index
  end
end
```

So in Posts#index action, how do I check if which route to index action is matched? (index or archived) There should be a clean way of doing this.

Comment: Are you asking whether if there are multiple routes pointing at a single action whether you can determine at runtime which one was matched?

Comment: I want to determine at runtime which one was matched

Comment: Really? You're going to throw down votes at my completely unrelated answers to questions you didn't ask yourself because you're upset with me?

Comment: 'current_path' == 'posts/index'.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> rake routes

and see the all routes in your application. Output will be like this.

```
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)  welcome#index
        users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
              POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
         root        /                         welcome#index
```

Your should go through this.. [Learn routing better from here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/routing.html)

Comment: That is not what I have asked.

Comment: Why dont u see ur server log,.... It will be like "started get /some/something"  when u request for a page.